# Split csv file by number of fields (each line different) to different target endpoints

Tags: apache-camel

I created a processor that reads a csv file that contains lines with different field counts. The producer's constructor gets a list of integers that tell it what lines are of interest (e.g. lines with 13 or 65 fields).

The output should be a byte[] for each field count - so i would have one byte[] with all lines with 13 fields and one with all lines with 65 fields.

I thought i could create a new exchange for each block and set a header value "fieldCount". The output of this processor would go into a choice().when(header...) route - routing each block to a different set of endpoints.

But how to create new exchanges? I read [this](http://camel.apache.org/how-do-i-write-a-custom-processor-which-sends-multiple-messages.html) and got the producer template this way `ProducerTemplate producer = exchange.getContext().createProducerTemplate();` but i always get `defaultEndpoint must be specified`. But my processor is not and should not aware of any endpoints. What is a "defaultendpoint"? How to set it properly?

I also looked into split()-pattern but this seems to be not of much help in my case. With it i could change my processor to emit List> and just split but with it the choice/when part is more complex or i need a second processor that creates a byte[] with a header set from each Map.

So what is the best approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the simplest approach is something like:

```
public class MyRouteBuilder extends RouteBuilder {  

   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {
     from("file://file.csv") 
       .split(body(String.class).tokenize("\n"))     
       .processor(new FieldCountHeaderProcessor())  
       .aggregate(header("fieldCount"))
       .processor(new ByteArrayConverterProcessor()) 
       .choice()
       .when(header("fieldCount").isEqualTo("13")).to("direct:ENDPOINT_FOR_13_FIELDS")   
       .when(header("fieldCount").isEqualTo("65")).to("direct:ENDPOINT_FOR_65_FIELDS")     
       .endChoice();
   }
}
```

The you only need to implement the `FieldCountHeaderProcessor` and the `ByteArrayConverterProcessor`.

You could also implement an `ByteArrayAggregationStrategy` (see [`AggragationStrategy`](http://camel.apache.org/aggregator2.html)) which would aggregate directly into a `byte[]`, eliminating the need for the `ByteArrayConverterProcessor`. For example:

```
public class MyRouteBuilderWithAggregationStrategy extends RouteBuilder {  

   @Override
   public void configure() throws Exception {
     from("file://file.csv") 
       .split(body(String.class).tokenize("\n"))     
       .processor(new FieldCountHeaderProcessor())  
       .aggregate(header("fieldCount"), new ByteArrayAggregationStrategy())
       .choice()
       .when(header("fieldCount").isEqualTo("13")).to("direct:ENDPOINT_FOR_13_FIELDS")   
       .when(header("fieldCount").isEqualTo("65")).to("direct:ENDPOINT_FOR_65_FIELDS")     
       .endChoice();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

in meantime i created another solution that is also working:

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from(DIRECT_IN).process(new MyProcessor(Lists.newArrayList(FIELD_COUNT_1, FIELD_COUNT_2))).split().body().choice()
                   .when(new CheckFieldCount(FIELD_COUNT_1))
                   .to(MOCK_FIELD_COUNT1)
                   .when(new CheckFieldCount(FIELD_COUNT_2))
                   .to(MOCK_FIELD_COUNT2)
                   .otherwise()
                   .to(MOCK_NOT_RELEVANT);
}
```

"MyProcessor" processes a csv-byte[] with different field counts to List. "CsvBlock" is a primitive class that contains the fieldCount (int) and the data (byte[]). "CheckFieldCount" implements predicate it just checks the given int against that one in exchange's data.
In this scenario CsvBlock is sent to mock. for my real code i would need another processor to extract data from CsvBlock (primitive code but another class).
At first glance i think Ricardo's way is the better one, but it would imply more work for me.